# rails mobile view color conflict between jquery-mobile and global css theme

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, jquery-mobile, colors

I'm searching since this morning without finding a full working solution.

I have a rails apps with a full responsive theme. I also have a form duplicated for the mobile (only one view to interact with mobile specifications)

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <label for="amount">Price :</label>
    <input type="range" id="slider-fill" name="video[amount]" value="0.25" min="0.01" max="0.5" step="0.01"/>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :public %>
    <select name="video[priv_pub]" id="flip-1" data-role="slider">
        <option value=true selected>on</option>
        <option value=false>off</option>
    </select>     
  </div>
```

I want to be able to customize the slider and the toggle, that is partially done adding the code below at the top of my view (find on stackoverflow) :

```
<style>
.ui-btn-active { color: #FFFFFF !important; background: #f69e19 !important; background-color: none !important; border-color: #975c02 !important; }
</style>
```

problem : the slider and the toggle range stay with blue border.

I use this code in the desktop view which works like a charm but I didn't success to adapt it for the mobile view :

```
.ui-slider-range { 
    border-color: #975c02;
    background: #f69e19; 
}
```

Ideally I would like the focus on the title field is orange too :)

thanks for advices

Comment: I just realized that I was not looking in the good way ... it seems that some code like .ui-slider-range:focus{ outline: 1 #f69e19 !important; } could make the trick .. still testing et searching :)

Comment: i found this code that works .ui-slider .ui-slider-handle:focus { outline:2px solid #f69e19 } but do not solve my problem ... because i still see under the outline the gradient border ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since this is an old question, I finally find some working code :

```
<% content_for :css_includes do -%>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" %>
<% end -%>

<style>
.ui-btn-active { color: #FFFFFF !important; background: #ff4486 !important; background-color: none !important; }
</style>

<% content_for :javascript_includes do %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js", "jquery.mobile.utils.js" %>
<% end %>
```

and the part of form

```
  <div class="field">
    <label for="amount">Price to sell (0.01BTC increments):</label>
    <input name="video[amount]" id="slider-fill" value="0.25" min="0.01" max="0.5" step="0.01" type="range" data-highlight="true" >
  </div><br />

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :public %>
    <select name="video[priv_pub]" id="flip-1" data-role="slider">
        <option value="false">Off</option>
        <option value="true" selected>On</option>
    </select>
  </div><br />
```

with the code above, I am able to have the choosen color theme for my two rails components : slide bar and toggle switch on/off